# How do I copy a word document with pictures into a Blogger post?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007, blogging

I am trying to copy a Word document with some formatting (e.g. bulleted lists) and pictures to a blog post using Google's Blogger.  When I do direct copy/paste, everything seems to copy over adequately except that the pictures show up as blank white boxes.

What I want:

- Pictures to show up in the blog just like in the Word document
- Formatting to at least be similar to the original document
- The text in the document to be searchable (no PDF's or anything like that)

What I have tried:

- Direct copy/paste from Word to Blogger
- Saving the Word doc as a web page and then copying the HTML into Blogger

What I am using:

- Microsoft Word 2007
- Windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to copy-paste from Word into [Windows Live Writer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-live/essentials-other#essentials=writerother) and not have the resultant blog post be too mangled which would otherwise require manual fixing:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 2):

Try uploading the document to [Google Drive](https://www.google.com/intl/en_GB/drive/start/index.html?authuser=0), opening the document from there into Google Docs, and then copying and pasting into the Blogger. Just an idea!

Answer (score 2):

Word documents and Web pages are not directly compatible. They are made up of very different formats.

You have to copy and paste the text, then use the blogging site tools to format the text. Then you have to export the pictures from the Word document, save them in some folder, then upload them to the blog page using Blogger upload tools, and place the pictures in their correct places.

It's a bit of work, but it's the only clean way. Other than that, you can only offer a link for readers to download the document.

Comment: Yeah that is the process I am trying to avoid.  If I were copying technical documentation with a bunch of little icons to show the user what button I am referring to, that could take quite a while

Answer (score 0):

Converting via Docs / Drive is indeed the best approach.

However I do not think that it works universally for pictures.   You may find that that you need to load them to Picasa-web-albums (PWA) first, and then use their PWA links to fix up your post.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure with pictures, but you can copy and convert the content to HTML through  online utilities such as http://wordtohtml.net/